# why I cannot search words in dictionary with the url?

Tags: dictionary

Why  I cannot search words in dictionary with the url, for example
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/Tea
returns its homepage, rather than the vocabulray page?

Comment: Seems to work fine without a capital 'T'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this.

`https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/<word>`

You will get directly to the page. Please note that this is case sensitive. So you need to write `tea` and not `Tea`. Just replease the `<word>` with a word - If it exist then it will show you the page, if not then you will be redirected to the FrontPage. Or if you want to just use the search

```
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=<word>
```